# How to dynamically make an interface key required (or make it optional)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a type

```
interface Test {
    foo: number;
    bar?: {
        name: string;
    };
}

const obj: Test;
// obj.bar is optional right now
```

But let's say I have `doSomething(obj)` and this method will make `bar` required and set it. I want `doSomething` to then return a new type where `bar` is required now.

Of course, I want this to be dynamic - as in, I don't want to create `interface TestRequired` and manually return that type.

Is this possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to change a property from optional to required is to intersect the original interface with a type where the containing only that property, but required. You can easily create such a type using `Required` and `Pick`:

```
declare const obj2: Test & Required<Pick<Test, 'bar'>>;
obj2.bar.name // bar is required so this is ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=48&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIwD2JAXMiAK4C2ARtANwFH1xQD8l+RfVcWhEpYooAOYs+AXxbS8eACYQEAGw4oEJEFmQl6AK0rosLVRGxxkAXj2GAdOyjIA9C+RXgGQjgFCRYGIgksjSyAA+yNQgyjCgEIrISirqUJrauvoGAEzGmNgAZMgAShAAjtTAaYoAPAAKwAgA1jUmYAA0yADkTl0AfH0sWdmOHPYggihuyE7IXshpFVUJyBgkyGAAFvPzJE1JQA)

Also note that if your function changes an existing object, you can use a custom type assertion to change the original type:

```
const obj: Test = { foo: 0}
let a = obj.bar // a is  { name: string; } | undefined 

obj.bar.name // err
function doSomething(o: Test): asserts o is Test & Required<Pick<Test, 'bar'>> {
    o.bar = { name: ""}
}

doSomething(obj)

obj.bar.name // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIwD2JAXMiAK4C2ARtANwFH1xQD8l+RfVcWhEpYooAOYs+AXxbS8eBCRBZkJegCtK6VQF5cxMpQAM8gDYRscZPvUaAdOyjIA9C+TXgGQjgFCRYGIgksjSyAA+yNQgACYQMKAQMcgKdo4c9iCCKG7I0FB4MNEIYMDKyDEkAMokQmAAFhIAFBRomGAAlJRwGBjQYN4kyF5tqgBkyABKEACO1MBQSQA8AArACADWSzpgADTIAOROBwB8J7ishGlONgZZ-sgARI-y8niVNXWNwS2aHamadJQTLZVzuEgbFJAA)

You could also make a function that adds `bar` but a type assertion is necessary:

```
function addBar(o: Test) {
    o.bar = { name: "" }
    return o as Test & Required<Pick<Test, 'bar'>> ;
}

let obj = addBar({ foo: 0 });
obj.bar.name;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIwD2JAXMiAK4C2ARtANwFH1xQD8l+RfVcWhEpYooAOYs+AXxbS8eGNRAIwwEiGRwAJtoBCHABQU0mMAEpcrQiQB07KMgC8uAUMoAiD8nl8oEMGooTRItDFMsZAAyZAAlCABHamB-bQAeAAVgBABrNPQsABpkAHIHEoA+CuQ5BQAbAOQSegArZy1dAyhDHGIySgAGH3MWZpb7DlsQQQgWPCA)

Comment: Can I make this a function? As in `const y = makeRequired(x, 'the-key')`

Comment: @Kousha You can make it but it requires an assertion control flow analysis will not change the type of `o` on assignment

Answer (score 3):

Of course. You can add or remove the optional modifier by property name or generally:

```
// StdLib already has the the type Partial<T> and Required<T> to make all properties of T optional or required respectively.

// Makes the named properties of T optional:
type PartialSome<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>

// Makes the named properties of T required:
type RequiredSome<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>
```

So your example might then look like this:

```
interface Test {
    foo: number;
    bar?: {
        name: string;
    };
}

declare function doSomething<T extends {bar?: any}>(obj: T): RequiredSome<T, "bar">;
const obj: Test;
const other = doSomething(obj);
other.bar // bar is required!
```

---

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=53&pln=7&pc=43#code/PTAEGUBcBMBkEsBGoCGAbATgUxdAnqABYoDOokhW5l5eADlQAooaTzoA8AKgHzkD2oALYoA1lXRpQdDPwat4WMvwBmoLqDlt+AO3QA6AFCGQoALJil1KnqFZo02fLZXV6zXW160ALkOR6JhY2dHB+O24AGlAAaVAsAA9ILB1oMnE8N15QAF5QAHkheEgo2L4AMlBmBU5GeABjUVKYnh5jUwtxMgobFDsHGTksBVc1DWwARwBXeGxoPwCGUAAlLGnZ+zCIrmi4xOTU9KxMsb48jUrV9bmOOsbm1vbgMNBMqYx4hL66NCoigHNCJBrDpQGh+PxRGD4OJqPASH5DPAdMkMCoUPUqFwlMCAN6GUCE0AqCE+UA6KZCRDDADcBKJiBYAH4yfiiezyX0sGSSJAMMj-nT2QBfOnC4zQLD1NAsKgqKY6epeUDQfhbLAUAXcT4HNKgXGMjAs1A6PDCngACn4iAAVmSuABKMlXGZzdWlABEho9PDpkulstA9V0vM0tvtOLphmDOlD-B6HzyqvVmp0-yttoddPjlAw+kNoFMBfh+ts3NAvP5aeF0WKoBLk1d9gAhIYgA)